# Custom font is not rendered to golden images when package is provided

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a custom font defined in module `theme`. This module is a dependency in module `widgets`.

A widget in widgets module applies custom font like below

```
style: TextStyle(
  fontSize: fontSize,
  fontFamily: "IconActions",
  package: "theme"
)
```

It works fine.

Unfortunately this custom font is not rendered on golden images. I have to remove the `package: "theme"` to fix that. But that breaks the app and the font is not displayed any more.
So basically I can have the font working correctly in the production code or the test code, but never both.

The custom font is loaded in `setUp` method of the test

```
final fontData = File('assets/fonts/IconActions.ttf')
  .readAsBytes()
  .then((bytes) => ByteData.view(Uint8List.fromList(bytes).buffer));
final fontLoader = FontLoader('IconActions')..addFont(fontData);
await fontLoader.load();
```

Am I missing something, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically the solution is to remove `package: "theme"` from the TextStyle to make it work. But that's the half of the solution, because as I mentioned in the question now golden files have the font renderer correctly, but the font doesn't work in the app.

To make it work in the app we need given project structure:

pubspec.yaml (module `theme`)

```
flutter:
  fonts:
   - family 'ComicSans'
     fonts:
     - asset: packages/theme/fonts/ComicSans.ttf
```

widget.dart (module `theme`)

```
style: TextStyle(
  fontSize: fontSize,
  fontFamily: "ComicSans",
)
```

Now in module `widgets`, which is the module that contains `main.dart` with its `main` function that you run, you have to define the font again:

pubspec.yaml (module `widgets`)

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  theme:
    path: ../path/to/theme/module

flutter:
  fonts:
   - family 'ComicSans'
     fonts:
     - asset: packages/theme/fonts/ComicSans.ttf
```

Now the font is correctly displayed in both the app and the golden images.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this exact issue for the last year and also couldn't get font loading to work within tests.. did not know that it was specifically the `package` argument that was breaking it, so thank you for updating with that result.

As for another workaround, there is a way to have the best of both worlds where you can have your standalone font package and not have to declare your packaged font files in your app that is using it.

For example, we have a company branding/typography package which we use across multiple apps that contains all our pre-configured `TextStyle` declarations, and another standalone package which has custom generated `IconData` that is stored within a `*.ttf` file (like FontAwesome).

#### The package side:

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
  fonts:
    - family: MyFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MyFont.ttf
          weight: 400

    # etc
```

The packaged `TextStyle`:

```dart
class BrandStyles {
  static const _packageName = '<package_name>';

  static const headline1Style = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: 'MyFont',
    fontSize: 60.0,
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    height: 1.16,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    package: _packageName,
  );


  // etc

}
```

Golden test

```dart
void main() {
  final widget = MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        // use custom extension method to remove `package` value
        headline1: BrandStyles.headline1Style.trimFontPackage(),
      ),
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: StylesExample()),
    ),
  );

  setUp(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final file = File('path/to/packaged/asset/MyFont.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
    final bytes = Future<ByteData>.value(file.buffer.asByteData());

    await (FontLoader('MyFont')..addFont(bytes)).load();
  });

  testWidgets('Golden typography test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
    await expectLater(
        find.byType(MaterialApp), matchesGoldenFile('goldens/typography.png'));
  });
}

extension StylingExtensions on TextStyle {
  
  TextStyle trimFontPackage() {
    return TextStyle(
      inherit: inherit,
      color: color,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      fontWeight: fontWeight,
      fontStyle: fontStyle,
      letterSpacing: letterSpacing,
      wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
      textBaseline: textBaseline,
      height: height,
      locale: locale,
      foreground: foreground,
      background: background,
      shadows: shadows,
      fontFeatures: fontFeatures,
      decoration: decoration,
      decorationColor: decorationColor,
      decorationStyle: decorationStyle,
      decorationThickness: decorationThickness,
      debugLabel: debugLabel,
      /// `replaceAll` only required if loading multiple fonts, 
      /// otherwise set value to your single `fontFamily` name
      fontFamily: fontFamily.replaceAll('packages/<package_name>/', ''),
    );
  }
}
```

Or if like me, you have the same issue with custom icons, the same can be done within your golden test for your custom `IconData` with a similar extension method, removing the `fontPackage` value:

```dart
extension IconExtensions on IconData {
  IconData convertToGolden() => IconData(
        this.codePoint,
        fontFamily: this.fontFamily,
      );
}
```

#### Your app side

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
# ...

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  <package_name>:
    git:
      url: <url_to_hosted_package>.git
      ref: <release_tag>
```

main.dart

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: BrandStyles.headline1Style,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

There is now no longer a need to declare your fonts within your apps `pubspec.yaml`, or even have the style package(s) within the same project/repository as your implementing app.