# Golden tests with custom icon font class

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a custom made icon font .ttf which I use within my apps as `IconData`, allowing for use the same way you would with Flutter's built-in material icons.

My custom font class:

```dart
class MyIcons {
    MyIcons._();

    static const iconFontFamily = 'MyIcons';
    static const iconFontPackage = 'my_icon_package';

    /// edit_outline
    static const IconData edit_outline = IconData(0xe000, fontFamily: iconFontFamily, fontPackage: iconFontPackage);


  // etc
}
```

Usage:

```dart
Icon(
  MyIcons.edit_outline,
  size: 24,
)
```

And all works well within the app. However now I am trying to generate golden test files to ensure my icons work as expected after I've updated the .ttf, but the icons are always only replaced with the test Ahem font squares.

If I use Flutter's default icons, and set `uses-material-design: true` in the `pubspec.yaml`, this allows the default icons to be rendered properly within the golden test files, however no matter what I try I cannot get my own icons to be rendered.

Other things I've tried and been unsuccessful with:

- [eBay's golden_toolkit package](https://pub.dev/packages/golden_toolkit)
- [Loading assets within tests](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12999)
- [FontLoader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FontLoader-class.html) and manually referencing the icons codepoint, fontFamily and package

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the gotchas with this thanks to [a related question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60616139/custom-font-is-not-rendered-to-golden-images-when-package-is-provided)

There is a way to have the best of both worlds where you can have your standalone font package and not have to declare your packaged font files in your app that is using it.

For example, we have a company branding/typography package which we use across multiple apps that contains all our pre-configured `TextStyle` declarations, and another standalone package which has custom generated `IconData` that is stored within a `*.ttf` file (like FontAwesome).

#### The package side:

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/fonts/
  fonts:
    - family: MyFont
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/MyFont.ttf
          weight: 400

    # etc
```

The packaged `TextStyle`:

```dart
class BrandStyles {
  static const _packageName = '<package_name>';

  static const headline1Style = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: 'MyFont',
    fontSize: 60.0,
    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    height: 1.16,
    letterSpacing: 0,
    package: _packageName,
  );


  // etc

}
```

Golden test

```dart
void main() {
  final widget = MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        // use custom extension method to remove `package` value
        headline1: BrandStyles.headline1Style.trimFontPackage(),
      ),
    ),
    home: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: StylesExample()),
    ),
  );

  setUp(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final file = File('path/to/packaged/asset/MyFont.ttf').readAsBytesSync();
    final bytes = Future<ByteData>.value(file.buffer.asByteData());

    await (FontLoader('MyFont')..addFont(bytes)).load();
  });

  testWidgets('Golden typography test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(widget);
    await expectLater(
        find.byType(MaterialApp), matchesGoldenFile('goldens/typography.png'));
  });
}

extension StylingExtensions on TextStyle {
  
  TextStyle trimFontPackage() {
    return TextStyle(
      inherit: inherit,
      color: color,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      fontSize: fontSize,
      fontWeight: fontWeight,
      fontStyle: fontStyle,
      letterSpacing: letterSpacing,
      wordSpacing: wordSpacing,
      textBaseline: textBaseline,
      height: height,
      locale: locale,
      foreground: foreground,
      background: background,
      shadows: shadows,
      fontFeatures: fontFeatures,
      decoration: decoration,
      decorationColor: decorationColor,
      decorationStyle: decorationStyle,
      decorationThickness: decorationThickness,
      debugLabel: debugLabel,
      /// `replaceAll` only required if loading multiple fonts, 
      /// otherwise set value to your single `fontFamily` name
      fontFamily: fontFamily.replaceAll('packages/<package_name>/', ''),
    );
  }
}
```

Or if like me, you have the same issue with custom icons, the same can be done within your golden test for your custom `IconData` with a similar extension method, removing the `fontPackage` value:

```dart
extension IconExtensions on IconData {
  IconData convertToGolden() => IconData(
        this.codePoint,
        fontFamily: this.fontFamily,
      );
}
```

#### Your app side

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
# ...

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  <package_name>:
    git:
      url: <url_to_hosted_package>.git
      ref: <release_tag>
```

main.dart

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: BrandStyles.headline1Style,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

There is now no longer a need to declare your fonts within your apps `pubspec.yaml`, or even have the style package(s) within the same project/repository as your implementing app.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the other answers i was able to solve this problem for myself and found out, that it is possible to have a shorter solution for it. Without adding extension methods and special themeData for a golden test.

The following code snippet loads (icon-)/fonts from three different sources, a bundled asset, the material icons and fluent icons for windows.

I hope this code will help some of you in the future to have easier handling for golden tests.

**flutter_test_config.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:file/local.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:platform/platform.dart';

Future<void> testExecutable(FutureOr<void> Function() testMain) async {
  setUpAll(() async {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    // loads a font that is bundled in your package
    final fontVariable = rootBundle.load('lib/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-VariableFont.ttf');
    final fontItalic = rootBundle.load('lib/fonts/Open_Sans/OpenSans-Italic-VariableFont.ttf');

    // here you maybe need to load more types, when you have a specific bold style as well
    final fontLoader = FontLoader('OpenSans')
      ..addFont(fontVariable)
      ..addFont(fontItalic);

    await fontLoader.load();


    // loads a font that is bundled in a different package, here for example from the fluent icons package (https://pub.dev/packages/fluentui_system_icons) 

    final fluentRegularIcon = rootBundle.load('packages/fluentui_system_icons/fonts/FluentSystemIcons-Regular.ttf');
    final fluentFilledIcon = rootBundle.load('packages/fluentui_system_icons/fonts/FluentSystemIcons-Filled.ttf');

    // there is no need to write extension methods or create specific themes, you only need to add the packages/package_name to the font name.
    final fluentRegularLoader = FontLoader('packages/fluentui_system_icons/FluentSystemIcons-Regular')
      ..addFont(fluentRegularIcon);
    final fluentFilledLoader = FontLoader('packages/fluentui_system_icons/FluentSystemIcons-Filled')
      ..addFont(fluentFilledIcon);

    await fluentRegularLoader.load();
    await fluentFilledLoader.load();


    // loads the material icon font
    final materialIcon = _loadMaterialIcon();

    final materialLoader = FontLoader('MaterialIcons')..addFont(materialIcon);

    await materialLoader.load();
  });

  // runs your golden tests
  await testMain();
}

// see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/74131/files
// Loads the cached material icon font.
// Only necessary for golden tests. Relies on the tool updating cached assets before
// running tests.
Future<ByteData> _loadMaterialIcon() async {
  const FileSystem fs = LocalFileSystem();
  const Platform platform = LocalPlatform();
  final Directory flutterRoot = fs.directory(platform.environment['FLUTTER_ROOT']);

  final File iconFont = flutterRoot.childFile(
    fs.path.join(
      'bin',
      'cache',
      'artifacts',
      'material_fonts',
      'MaterialIcons-Regular.otf',
    ),
  );

  final Future<ByteData> bytes = Future<ByteData>.value(
    iconFont.readAsBytesSync().buffer.asByteData(),
  );

  return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to load the icon font manually just like any other custom font in flutter tests.

I used parts of a solution from the Flutter Gallery demo app:
https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/master/golden_test/testing/font_loader.dart

And for material icons I used a solution found here:

issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/75391

code: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/74131/files

Some gotchas are:

- it seems like the font loading must be done outside of test function so perform it first then run the test.
- make sure the filenames and font families are correct everywhere.

Given that there is a correctly set up custom font called 'Matter' and a correctly setup custom icon font that exists in a "fonts" directory in the root of the project -->

Demo code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:[your_path_to_icon_definition_file]/custom_icons.dart';
import 'package:file/file.dart' as f;
import 'package:file/local.dart' as l;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:platform/platform.dart' as p;

Future<void> main() async {
  await loadFonts();
  run();
}

void run() {
  group('mobile', () {
    testWidgets('Test font and icon loading', (tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Matter', // Define the custom font family.
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('AppBar'),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Text('test'),
              Icon(CustomIcons.camera), // Custom icon file from for example fluttericon.com
              Icon(Icons.add), // material icons ('uses-material-design: true' Must exist in pubspec.yaml)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ));

      expect(find.byType(MaterialApp), findsOneWidget);

      await expectLater(
        find.byType(MaterialApp),
        matchesGoldenFile('goldens/material_app.png'),
      );
    });
  });
}

/// Load fonts to make sure they show up in golden tests.
Future<void> loadFonts() async {
  await _load(await loadFontsFromFontsDir());
  await _loadMaterialIconFont();
}

// Loads the cached material icon font.
// Only necessary for golden tests. Relies on the tool updating cached assets before
// running tests.
Future<void> _loadMaterialIconFont() async {
  const f.FileSystem fs = l.LocalFileSystem();
  const p.Platform platform = p.LocalPlatform();
  final flutterRoot = fs.directory(platform.environment['FLUTTER_ROOT']);

  final iconFont = flutterRoot.childFile(
    fs.path.join(
      'bin',
      'cache',
      'artifacts',
      'material_fonts',
      'MaterialIcons-Regular.otf',
    ),
  );

  final bytes = Future<ByteData>.value(iconFont.readAsBytesSync().buffer.asByteData());

  await (FontLoader('MaterialIcons')..addFont(bytes)).load();
}

/// Assumes a fonts dir in root of project
Map<String, List<Future<ByteData>>> loadFontsFromFontsDir() {
  final fontFamilyToData = <String, List<Future<ByteData>>>{};
  final currentDir = path.dirname(Platform.script.path);
  final fontsDirectory = path.join(
    currentDir,
    'fonts',
  );
  for (var file in Directory(fontsDirectory).listSync()) {
    if (file is File) {
      final fontFamily = path.basenameWithoutExtension(file.path).split('-').first;
      (fontFamilyToData[fontFamily] ??= []).add(file.readAsBytes().then((bytes) => ByteData.view(bytes.buffer)));
    }
  }
  return fontFamilyToData;
}

Future<void> _load(Map<String, List<Future<ByteData>>> fontFamilyToData) async {
  final waitList = <Future<void>>[];
  for (final entry in fontFamilyToData.entries) {
    print('entry.key=${entry.key}');
    final loader = FontLoader(entry.key);
    for (final data in entry.value) {
      loader.addFont(data);
    }
    waitList.add(loader.load());
  }
  await Future.wait(waitList);
}
```

Resulting in:
[image: golden_example]

Comment: thanks, this is more or less how I ended up solving it myself as I commented on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66344917/6716211